# How to keep userdata after websocket socket.io reconnecting?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have socket.io server,

1. i connect web browsers to this server,
2. and also i need to connect devices like arduino, which are not browsers, so they dont have sessions.

when you lost connection, all the devices/browsers do a reconnection, but how can i keep subscribers (devices/browsers) to get same data like you read from database at the first connection (permissions, name etc., who control who etc.)

for browsers i can save this subscribers data based on session_id but devices has not any session_id?

is there a mechanism inside socket.io which can recognize the same client, bcs after reconnection it always change the client.id

Answer (score 0):

You should invent your own "session_id" on your devices and process reconnects manually. Socket.io is only broadcaster without any persist stuff.